# Mock Service in Cloud

Tags: integration

Looking for recommendation. Trying to make integration services in Salesforce, to read data from another system (which is still not built). But the response format is agreed upon. How do I, as a Salesforce developer making the callouts be able to test the same?  Is there any mock service provider that I can leverage?  Any other method to look at?

Comment: Are you asking how to write Apex unit tests for web services? or are you asking for a mock provider to test the compatibility of the service with Salesforce, at a POC level?

Comment: The latter.  Not unit tests.  Looking for a mock provider, that can return response in a certain format that I want.

Comment: I would develop the class and then, basically, force it to return a constant string instead of making an actual callout...

Comment: @SebastianKessel The platform will not allow an actual callout from a class invoked by a test class.

Comment: Jesse, the OP does not want a test class... she wants to test their code before the class on the other side is done. At least that is what I understood from her posts.

Comment: Yes. Thanks Sebastian..  I think what you said would suffice.  Though not actually making a call outside the org, I guess it would help me in making functional demos.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your mock response in a static resource, then have your test class set up the mock.

```
StaticResourceCalloutMock mock = new StaticResourceCalloutMock();
mock.setStaticResource('YourStaticResourceMock');
mock.setStatusCode(200);
mock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

//start tests
Test.startTest();

Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, mock);
```

Your tested class will return the mock response on your web service call.

Comment: This is not what the OP has asked for. Please read her 2nd comment. "No unit tests".